# where is my downloaded ringtone?

Tags: ringtone

First-time windows phone user. Downloaded successfully a third party ringtone, but I don't know where to find it on my phone, so I can set it as the default ringtone.

Comment: If one of the answers still do not work for you, can you let us know which app you are referencing?

Answer (score 1):

If the third party app saved it correctly, go to Settings --> ringtones + sounds --> Ringtone.

The custom ringtones will be at the top of the list in a Custom group followed by the stock ringtones on the Windows Phone Group. You can tap any one of these to select it.

If the third party app did not correctly save it, there is nothing you can do other than find a better ringtone app.

If you have the file on a computer and can connect your phone, you can explore the phone's folders. There is a ringtone folder. Paste your ringtone in this folder and if it meets the requirements it will automatically show as a [ringtone](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/start/create-ringtones).

- In MP3 or WMA format.
- Less than 40 seconds.
- Less than 1 MB.
- Not protected with digital rights management (DRM).

Answer (score 0):

To add to caschw's answer since he's only answering Windows Phone 8. here is what you have to do on **Windows Phone 7(.8)**

First off it has the same requirements as Cashchw mentioned but you also need to set the Genre in the correct way.

**Using Zune**

- Connect your phone to your PC and open Zune
- find the file you want to upload as a ringtone
- rightclick the file and click edit
- change the genre to ringtone
- click OK.
- upload the file to your phone

**Ringtone from Text message**

- tap "Get media content now" in the text message to download the ringtone
- Tap and hold the file and tap "Save as ringtone"

**source:**

- wp7: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/start/create-ringtones
- wp8: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/start/add-ringtones-to-my-phone